# Pass data from factory to Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I have an existing Angular Factory and I'm having some trouble inserting some new code that needs to pass the results of a $resource get to my Angular Controller.  I'm trying to do this in the "sendFilesToController()" function shown below.  I'm not sure of the syntax.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

---

My factory looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('ooApp.controllers')
        .factory('fileManager', fileManager);


    fileManager.$inject = ['$q', 'fileManagerClient', 'appInfo', 'sharedPropertiesSvc', 'FileSvc', '$location', 'growl', ];

    function fileManager($q, fileManagerClient, appInfo, sharedPropertiesSvc, FileSvc, $location, growl) {
        var service = {
            files: [],
            load: load,
            upload: upload,
            remove: remove,
            fileExists: fileExists,
            pass: pass,
            status: {
                uploading: false
            }
        };

        return service;

        function load() {
            appInfo.setInfo({ busy: true, message: "loading files" })

            service.files.length = 0;

            return fileManagerClient.query()
                                .$promise
                                .then(function (result) {
                                    result.files
                                            .forEach(function (file) {
                                                service.files.push(file);
                                            });

                                    appInfo.setInfo({ message: "files loaded successfully" });

                                    return result.$promise;
                                },
                                function (result) {
                                    appInfo.setInfo({ message: "something went wrong: " + result.data.message });
                                    return $q.reject(result);
                                })
                                ['finally'](
                                function () {
                                    appInfo.setInfo({ busy: false });
                                });
        }

        function upload(files) {
            //ToDo Check that file extension exists here

                                            item.OversightId = oversightId;
                                            FileSvc.update({ Id: oversightId }, item).$promise.then(function (response) {
                                                var x = 5;


                                                sendFilesToController(id);


                                            });

                                            return result.$promise;
                                        },
                                        function (error) {
                                            appInfo.setInfo({ message: "something went wrong: " + error.data.message });
                                            sharedPropertiesSvc.setDuplicateFileSwitch(true);
                                            sharedPropertiesSvc.setDupFileMsg(error.data.error.message);

                                            var url = '/oa/?id=' + oversightId;
                                            $location.url(url);

                                            return $q.reject(error);
                                        })
                                        ['finally'](
                                        function () {
                                            appInfo.setInfo({ busy: false });
                                            service.status.uploading = false;
                                        });
        }

       function sendFilesToController(id) {
            //appInfo.setInfo({ busy: true, message: "deleting file " + file.ImageName });


            return {

                sendFiles: function () {

                    //return FileSvc.getById({ Id: oversightId }).$promise.then(function (response) {
                    //});
                    var files = {};
                    FileSvc.getById({ Id: id }).success(function (response) {
                        angular.copy(response, files);
                    });
                    return files;
                }

        }


        }

    }
})();
```

and in my controller I just have this:

```
 $scope.files = fileManagerClient.sendFiles(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

you misunderstanding the factory and controller usage....

define the factory =>

then inject the factory => into the controller that you want

```
angular.module('myExample', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, Factory) {

      console.log('Factory', Factory.word); 
  });

// factory
angular.module('myExample')
  .factory('Factory', function () {
    var factory = { };
    factory.word = 'example';
    return factory;
})
```

Comment: Thank you Joseph.  I understand what you are saying.  However, I'm not sure how to do it in the specific code that already exists.

Comment: just inject the factory and use the service , you could think the factory is the common lib for you

Comment: What i really want to do here is bind the files returned in the factory to $scope.item.Files in the controller.